# Trailing zeros appears after casting DOUBLE PRECISION to VARCHAR

Tags: casting, firebird, firebird-3.0

When trying to cast a `DOUBLE PRECISION` value to `VARCHAR`, I get a serie of 12 undesired trailing zeros.

**For example:**

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(2500 AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS VARCHAR(50))
FROM rdb$database
```

It produces the following unexpected result:

```
2500.000000000000
```

Expected result:

```
2500
```

What is causing this problem and how can this be avoided?

Comment: The obviously solution would be: don't cast to double precision, but I guess that is not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: In any case, although I don't know the specifics of this rendering (though it is likely done to preserve the 16-17 decimal digit precision of a double precision), it is hardly uncommon (eg in Java `System.out.printf("%f%n", 2500D)` will print `2500.000000`, while `%g` instead of `%f` will print 2500.00, and `%s` will print 2500.0). If you provide your actual use case, it might be easier to provide a suitable solution (eg cast to decimal instead of double precision).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I would like to remove all the trailing zeros (and the decimal separator, if all decimals have been removed)

Comment: Well, you could do `trim(trailing '.' from trim(trailing '0' from CAST(CAST(2500 AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS VARCHAR(50))))` (optionally in the form of a stored function), the alternative is to look for a third party udf or udr that provides formatting options (or build such a udf or udr yourself).

Comment: You should not abuse database server for rendering pretty pictures for humans. That is the task for report generators and other client applications. Do not cast to `varchar`, pass it as it is, a number. Make client application spell that nmber to users as they like them. Not every nation uses point symbol as decimal separator. And there is no thousands separators there. So even Mark's solution is limited quick hack. Making pretty reports is task for report generator kinf of tools. Abusing RDBMS to do so would be ineffective at some tasks, impossbile at others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate workaround for this problem is to use

```sql
trim(trailing '.' from trim(trailing '0' from stringvalue))
```

You could wrap this in a PSQL function for easier reuse.

However, this is a risky solution as very large or very small numbers will be rendered in scientific notation, and this solution would strip zeroes from the exponent. As an example, the value `1.2e30` as string will be rendered as `1.200000000000000e+30`, but above solution will mangle that to `1.200000000000000e+3` (which is 1200).

As Arioch 'The already suggested in the comments, this is a problem better solved in the presentation layer of your application (which can then also take things like locale into account for things like decimal separator, thousand separator, etc).

Alternatively, you could try to find a third-party UDF or UDR (or build one yourself), that allows you to format numbers using the desired format.